# Issue in loading the Vector2 array in libGdx

Tags: java, android, vector, nullpointerexception, libgdx

In my Libgdx based android game, I am creating a Vector2 to load all the points needed for my game. I am getting the NullPointerException when the code reaches

```
points[i].add(burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate(),burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate()) ;
```

### Code

```
    points=new Vector2[100];
    for (int i=0;i<burstCellGrid.size();i++){
        System.out.println("i : " + i);
        System.out.println("burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate() : " + burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate());
        System.out.println("burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate() : " + burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate());
        points[i].add(burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate(),burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate()) ;
    }
```

### LogCat

```
i : 0
burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate() : 841.0
burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate() : 1314.0
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors inside the array are not instantiated so you  can not do `point[i].add` before instantiate it `point[i] = new Vector2()`

```
for (int i=0;i<burstCellGrid.size();i++){
            System.out.println("i : " + i);
            System.out.println("burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate() : " + burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate());
            System.out.println("burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate() : " + burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate());
            points[i] = new Vector2(burstCellGrid.get(i).getColCoordinate(),burstCellGrid.get(i).getRowCoordinate()) ;
        }
```

Good luck